# Sending Pause and DTMF input in android

Tags: android

I am Intercepting outgoing call following is my code of outgoing call interception

```
public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String calling_number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                setResultData("123,"+calling_number );
}
}
```

in android , is used for pause, but it is not working?
how can I send DTMF input or use pause, wait and  symbol?
I am stuck in it any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use p or w, not comma

Comment: Doesn't work in most cases. Comma works for emulators and some phones.