# Using tel: to initiate a call with a phone extension

Tags: android, html, mobile, anchor, tel

What is the proper way to format a tel: link with a phone extension? I've seen a few different suggestions, but I'm unclear on which one is the definitive approach.

```
<a href="tel:5555555,555">555-5555 ext. 555</a>
```

Using an android 2.3.4, I have been unable to make a call via a link that dials the phone extension.

[RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-3) indicates that this is the correct format:

```
extension = ";ext=" 1*phonedigit
```

But I'm not clear on what the 1* is for, nor have I been able to make that format work either.

Comment: See [Sending pause to dialer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5750773/687315). This doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 3):

The 1* is for the ABNF generative grammar used by RFC3966 and means 1 or more digits make up the extension field.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form for the ABNF used.

Answer (score 3):

You can try 
`<a href="tel:5555555p555">555-5555 ext. 555</a>`
the p is for 1 sec pause

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is written in ABNF notation which is described in [RFC2234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234).

The syntax for a `tel` URI is (abbreviated):

```
telephone-uri        = "tel:" telephone-subscriber
telephone-subscriber = global-number / local-number
global-number        = global-number-digits *par
local-number         = local-number-digits *par context *par
par                  = parameter / extension / isdn-subaddress
extension            = ";ext=" 1*phonedigit
```

The `"tel:"` and `";ext="` tokens are literal strings.
The `1*phonedigit` notation means one or more of the following productions (eg. `phonedigit`).

From what I can tell, the telephone number should be marked up as:

```
<a href="tel:5555555;ext=555">555-5555 ext. 555</a>
```

**Disclaimer**: I have never used phone number URIs and I don't know what the browser support is like. I'm not even sure this is the appropriate use of the `ext` parameter.

Note also that [RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.1.5) states that:

> Local numbers **MUST** have a `phone-context` parameter that identifies the scope of their validity.

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
<a href="tel:+18881234567">Make a call</a>
```

It is generally easier using the + at the beginning (requires you have a country code, but guarantees the phone identifies the number right).

Comment: What about a phone extension? That's the heart of the issue here.

Comment: In general you can't use extensions from the dialer that way, because they have to be punched in AFTER the connection gets made. However, you can try adding a semicolon or ***w*** and then the extension.

Comment: This is nothing to see with extensions.